# Is it possible to start real docker daemon in docker?

Tags: docker, rhel, docker-in-docker

I need to run docker inside of another docker for some reason.
Mapping docker.socket is not an option, I need real docker daemon to start within docker.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what [`jpetazzo/dind`](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind) experimented with a few years ago.

Today (2018), If you want to run Docker-in-Docker today, all you need to do is:

```
docker run --privileged -d docker:dind
```

He adds:

> ... And that's it; you get Docker running in Docker, thanks to the official Docker image, in its "Docker-in-Docker" flavor.
>   You can then connect to this Docker instance by starting another Docker container linking to the first one (which is a pretty amazing thing to do).

See its [official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/).